# What, exactly, is required to become a construction manager?

Tags: work-experience, career-switch, job-acceptance

Does one need experience as a laborer, such as a carpenter, to become a construction manager in addition to a bachelor's degree in construction management, or is the bachelor's degree, along with some experience in the field of construction management, the only thing that's necessary?

Thank you.

Comment: Re close votes: This is **not** _Too Broad_ as the question is clear, and is **not** asking for _Advice on a Specific Choice_ since there is no choice presented. If you don't know how to answer, leave it to those who do, or think of a better close reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms, the same way as you find the requirements for any job.

Look at job vacancy listings and examine what qualifications/experiences are necessary for applicants and judge whether you meet those requirements.

If you do, apply.

If you don't, see what you need to achieve to meet those requirements and do it.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing required to be a construction manager is for someone to hire you as one.

People have gotten that role from draughtsman, foreman, CAD design, architect, owners son and probably a lot of other things.